# simplify nested if statements

Tags: php, laravel

I'm implementing a search functionality and based on the query parameter i use a different class to search.

```
class Search { 

    public function getResults()
    {
        if (request('type') == 'thread') {
                $results = app(SearchThreads::class)->query();
        } elseif (request('type') == 'profile_post') {
                $results = app(SearchProfilePosts::class)->query();
        } elseif (request()->missing('type')) {
                $results = app(SearchAllPosts::class)->query();
     }

}
```

Now when i want to search threads i have the following code.

```
class SearchThreads{

        public function query()
        {
            $searchQuery = request('q');
            $onlyTitle = request()->boolean('only_title');

            if (isset($searchQuery)) {
                if ($onlyTitle) {
                    $query = Thread::search($searchQuery);
                } else {
                    $query = Threads::search($searchQuery);
                }
            } else {
                if ($onlyTitle) {
                    $query = Activity::ofThreads();
                } else {
                    $query = Activity::ofThreadsAndReplies();
                }
            }
        }

}
```

To explain the code.

If the user enters a search word ( **$searchQuery**)  then use **Algolia** to search, otherwise make a database query directly.

- If the user enters a search word

  1. Use the **Thread** index if the user **has** checked the **onlyTitle** checkbox
  2. Use the **Threads** index if the user **hasn't** checked the **onlyTitle** checkbox
- If the user doesn't enter a search word

  1. Get all the **threads** if the user **has** checked the **onlyTitle** checkbox
  2. Get all the **threads and replies** if the user **hasn't** checked the **onlyTitle** checkbox

Is there a pattern to simplify the nested if statements or should i just create a separate class for the cases where

1. a user has entered a search word
2. a user hasn't entered a search word

And inside each of those classes to check if the user has checked the **onlyTitle** checkbox

Comment: Can you share more details? This does not look like valid PHP code after all. Also, have a look at https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1804192/how-to-reduce-the-number-of-if-else-statements-in-php

Comment: Strange. The first version of this post did not include any function parts - `class Search { ` was immediately followed by the `if` statement

Comment: I'm unclear on what the problem is; it sounds like you have cosmetic concerns with your code?

Comment: Actually yes, I want to avoid having all these if else statements and make the code cleaner

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I would refactor this code to this:

Leave the request parameter to unify the search methods in an interface.

```
interface SearchInterface
{
    public function search(\Illuminate\Http\Request $request);
}

class Search {

    protected $strategy;

    public function __construct($search)
    {
        $this->strategy = $search;
    }

    public function getResults(\Illuminate\Http\Request $request)
    {
        return $this->strategy->search($request);
    }
}

class SearchFactory
{
    private \Illuminate\Contracts\Container\Container $container;

    public function __construct(\Illuminate\Contracts\Container\Container $container)
    {
        $this->container = $container;
    }

    public function algoliaFromRequest(\Illuminate\Http\Request  $request): Search
    {
        $type = $request['type'];
        $onlyTitle = $request->boolean('only_title');
        if ($type === 'thread' && !$onlyTitle) {
            return $this->container->get(Threads::class);
        }

        if ($type === 'profile_post' && !$onlyTitle) {
            return $this->container->get(ProfilePosts::class);
        }

        if (empty($type) && !$onlyTitle) {
            return $this->container->get(AllPosts::class);
        }

        if ($onlyTitle) {
            return $this->container->get(Thread::class);
        }

        throw new UnexpectedValueException();
    }

    public function fromRequest(\Illuminate\Http\Request $request): Search
    {
        if ($request->missing('q')) {
            return $this->databaseFromRequest($request);
        }
        return $this->algoliaFromRequest($request);
    }

    public function databaseFromRequest(\Illuminate\Http\Request $request): Search
    {
        $type = $request['type'];
        $onlyTitle = $request->boolean('only_title');
        if ($type === 'thread' && !$onlyTitle) {
            return $this->container->get(DatabaseSearchThreads::class);
        }

        if ($type === 'profile_post' && !$onlyTitle) {
            return $this->container->get(DatabaseSearchProfilePosts::class);
        }

        if ($type === 'thread' && $onlyTitle) {
            return $this->container->get(DatabaseSearchThread::class);
        }

        if ($request->missing('type')) {
            return $this->container->get(DatabaseSearchAllPosts::class);
        }

        throw new InvalidArgumentException();
    }
}


final class SearchController
{
    private SearchFactory $factory;

    public function __construct(SearchFactory $factory)
    {
        $this->factory = $factory;
    }

    public function listResults(\Illuminate\Http\Request $request)
    {
        return $this->factory->fromRequest($request)->getResults($request);
    }
}
```

The takeaway from this is it is very important to not involve the request in the constructors. This way you can create instances without a request in the application lifecycle. This is good for caching, testability and modularity. I also don't like the app and request methods as they pull variables out of thin air, reducing testability and performance.

Comment: Thanks a lot. Final remarks. So each SearchStrategy ( DatabaseSearchThread::class, Threads::class ) will take the request parameter and each of them has to decide wether to use it or not ( so all the DatabaseSearchStrategies will not use it at all but they will accept it as a parameter) right ?. Finally why don't you pass the SearchFactory in the Search class so in the SearchController you just use the Search class and call $search->getResults($request) directly. ?

Comment: Yes, the request parameter is provided everywhere. It is the cost of the abstraction.

Regarding the SearchFactory in the search class: It is a matter of taste. In my mind, the controller is only responsible for chaining logical actions, not implementing them. In this view, Search is an implementation of how to search something; the controller will chain the construction logic and initiate the search request. In your counterproposal, both actions would be dealt with in the Search class.

If you are satisfied with my answer, do not forget to mark it as a solution. It helps me a lot.

Answer (score 0):

```
class Search 
{
     public function __construct(){
             $this->strategy = app(SearchFactory::class)->create();
         }

        public function getResults()
        {
             return $this->strategy->search();
         }
}
```

```
class SearchFactory
{
    public function create()
    {
        if (request()->missing('q')) {
            return app(DatabaseSearch::class);
        } else {
            return app(AlgoliaSearch::class);
        }

    }
}
```

```
class AlgoliaSearch implements SearchInterface
{

    
    public function __construct()
    {
        $this->strategy = app(AlgoliaSearchFactory::class)->create();
    }
    public function search()
    {
        $this->strategy->search();
    }
}
```

```
class AlgoliaSearchFactory
{

    public function create()
    {
        if (request('type') == 'thread') {
            return app(Threads::class);
        } elseif (request('type') == 'profile_post') {
            return app(ProfilePosts::class);
        } elseif (request()->missing('type')) {
            return app(AllPosts::class);
        } elseif (request()->boolean('only_title')) {
            return app(Thread::class);
        }
    }
}
```

Where the classes created in the **AlgoliaSearchFactory** are algolia aggregators so the **search** method can be called on any of those classes.

Would something like this make it cleaner or even worse ?

Right now i have strategies that have strategies which sounds too much to me.

Answer (score 0):

I have tried to implement a good solution for you, but I had to make some assumptions about the code.

I decoupled the request from the constructor logic and gave the search interface a request parameter. This makes the intention clearer than just pulling the Request from thin air with the request function.

```
final class SearchFactory
{
    private ContainerInterface $container;

    /**
     * I am not a big fan of using the container to locate the dependencies.
     * If possible I would implement the construction logic inside the methods.
     * The only object you would then pass into the constructor are basic building blocks,
     * independent from the HTTP request (e.g. PDO, AlgoliaClient etc.)
     */
    public function __construct(ContainerInterface $container)
    {
        $this->container = $container;
    }

    private function databaseSearch(): DatabaseSearch
    {
        return // databaseSearch construction logic
    }

    public function thread(): AlgoliaSearch
    {
        return // thread construction logic
    }

    public function threads(): AlgoliaSearch
    {
        return // threads construction logic
    }

    public function profilePost(): AlgoliaSearch
    {
        return // thread construction logic
    }

    public function onlyTitle(): AlgoliaSearch
    {
        return // thread construction logic
    }

    public function fromRequest(Request $request): SearchInterface
    {
        if ($request->missing('q')) {
            return $this->databaseSearch();
        }

        // Fancy solution to reduce if statements in exchange for legibility :)
        // Note: this is only a viable solution if you have done correct http validation IMO
        $camelCaseType = Str::camel($request->get('type'));
        if (!method_exists($this, $camelCaseType)) {
            // Throw a relevent error here
        }

        return $this->$camelCaseType();
    }
}

// According to the code you provided, algoliasearch seems an unnecessary wrapper class, which receives a search interface, just to call another search interface. If this is the only reason for its existence, I would remove it
final class AlgoliaSearch implements SearchInterface {
    private SearchInterface $search;

    public function __construct(SearchInterface $search) {
        $this->search = $search;
    }

    public function search(Request $request): SearchInterface {
        return $this->search->search($request);
    }
}
```

I am also not sure about the point of the Search class. If it only effectively renames the search methods to getResults, I am not sure what the point is. Which is why I omitted it.

Comment: Maybe my explanation of the problem is not clear ( I mean the code is not clear ). To begin with the onlyTitle is not determined by the 'type' but by the 'only_title' parameter. Therefore, when you call the $request->get('type') you will not get a value for onlyTitle and thus the method will not be found. Additionally, when a type is given ( let's say for example that type == 'thread' ). there are two different strategies that can search 'thread' based on the request('q'), if request('q') exists then use Algolia to search 'thread' otherwise use Database to search 'thread'.

Comment: So in your answer you have the following line if ($request->missing('q')) {
            return $this->databaseSearch();
        }. When request('q'). is missing, then you I have to check what the request('type') is and what the value of the request('only_title') is in order to determine the searchStrategy

Comment: Yes, I would keep checking for positive cases, handling them and instantly returning it. That way you only use if statements, no else needed to reduce cognitive load

Comment: I added another very long answer. in case you have the time to check it and maybe better understand my issue.

Answer (score 0):

I had to write all this to make the problem understandable.

The **SearchFactory** takes all the required parameters and based on these parameters, it calls either **AlgoliaSearchFactory** or **DatabaseSearchFactory** to produce the final object that will be returned.

```
class SearchFactory
{
    protected $type;
    protected $searchQuery;
    protected $onlyTitle;
    protected $algoliaSearchFactory;
    protected $databaseSearchFactory;

    public function __construct(
        $type,
        $searchQuery,
        $onlyTitle,
        DatabaseSearchFactory $databaseSearchFactory,
        AlgoliaSearchFactory $algoliaSearchFactory
    ) {
        $this->type = $type;
        $this->searchQuery = $searchQuery;
        $this->onlyTitle = $onlyTitle;
        $this->databaseSearchFactory = $databaseSearchFactory;
        $this->algoliaSearchFactory = $algoliaSearchFactory;
    }

    public function create()
    {
        if (isset($this->searchQuery)) {
            return $this->algoliaSearchFactory->create($this->type, $this->onlyTitle);
        } else {
            return $this->databaseSearchFactory->create($this->type, $this->onlyTitle);
        }
    }
}
```

The **DatabaseSearchFactory** based on the **$type** and the **onlyTitle** parameters that are passed from the **SearchFactory** returns an object which is the final object that needs to be used in order to get the results.

```
class DatabaseSearchFactory
{
    public function create($type, $onlyTitle)
    {
        if ($type == 'thread' && !$onlyTitle) {
            return app(DatabaseSearchThreads::class);
        } elseif ($type == 'profile_post' && !$onlyTitle) {
            return app(DatabaseSearchProfilePosts::class);
        } elseif ($type == 'thread' && $onlyTitle) {
            return app(DatabaseSearchThread::class);
        } elseif (is_null($type)) {
            return app(DatabaseSearchAllPosts::class);
        }
    }
}
```

Same logic with **DatabaseSearchFactory**

```
class AlgoliaSearchFactory
{
    public function create($type, $onlyTitle)
    {
        if ($type == 'thread' && !$onlyTitle) {
            return app(Threads::class);
        } elseif ($type == 'profile_post' && !$onlyTitle) {
            return app(ProfilePosts::class);
        } elseif (empty($type) && !$onlyTitle) {
            return app(AllPosts::class);
        } elseif ($onlyTitle) {
            return app(Thread::class);
        }
    }
}
```

The objects that are created by **AlgoliaSearchFactory** have a method **search** which needs a **$searchQuery** value

```
interface AlgoliaSearchInterface
{
    public function search($searchQuery);
}
```

The objects that are created by **DatabaseSearchFactory** have a **search** method that doesn't need any parameters.

```
interface DatabaseSearchInterface
{
    public function search();
}
```

The class **Search** now takes as a parameter the final object that is produced by **SearchFactory** which can either implement **AlgoliaSearchInterface** or **DatabaseSearchInterface** that's why I haven't type hinted

The **getResults** method now has to find out the type of the **search** variable ( which interface it implements ) in order to either pass the **$searchQuery** as a parameter or not.

And that is how a **controller** can use the **Search** class to get the results.
class Search
{
protected $strategy;

```
    public function __construct($search)
    {
        $this->strategy = $search;
    }

    public function getResults()
    {
        if(isset(request('q')))
        {
            $results = $this->strategy->search(request('q'));
        }
        else
        {
            $results = $this->strategy->search();
        }
    }
}


class SearchController(Search $search)
{
    $results = $search->getResults();
}
```

According to all of @Transitive suggestions this is what I came up with. The only thing that I cannot solve is how to call **search** in the **getResults** method without having an if statement.